# My registration view doesnt post the input

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do a login and register view with c#, html and MVC. First of all, I have a table in my database called "Usuarios" with columns like: Username, Contrasena (Password), Email, etc). When i fill all the text boxes to test if my controller update my database (adding the new user) it doesnt work.

My RegisterClient() method in ClientController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RegisterClient(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         Cliente Client = new Cliente(model.NombreUsuario, model.Password, model.Nombre, model.Apellido, model.Domicilio, model.TipoDoc, model.NumeroDoc, model.Telefono);

         using (var db = new ContextoDB())
         {
             if (db.Usuarios.Any(u => u.NombreUsuario == Client.NombreUsuario))
             {
                 ViewBag.DuplicateMessage = "Nombre de usuario en uso.";
                 return View("RegisterClient", model);
             }

             db.Usuarios.Add(Client);
             db.SaveChanges();
         }
         ModelState.Clear();
         ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Registado excitosamente!";

         return RedirectToAction("RegistrationSuccess", "Account");
     } else
     {
         return View(model);
     }
 }
```

The RegisterClient View:

```
<div class="register-box">
    <h4 class="h4-header">Registro paso 2 de 2 </h4>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Register failed. Check your login details.")
    <fieldset class="fieldset-box client-field">
        <div class="user-info-box">
            <h3> Datos de la cuenta</h3>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NombreUsuario, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Usuario" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NombreUsuario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Email" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Contraseña" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Confirmar contraseña" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="personal-info-box">
            <h3> Datos personales</h3>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Nombre" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Apellido, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Apellido" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Domicilio, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Domicilio" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telefono, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Telefono" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroDoc, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Numero de documento" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="but-next next round" name="upvote" value="&#8250;" />
    </form>

    <a href="#" class="but-next next round">&#8250;</a>
</div>
```

When I fill all the boxes, it triggers the validation messages.

Comment: Why would it? Nothing in the code above calls the controller

Comment: And how can I do it? In the upvote button? I'm a noob at this.

Comment: Please see my answer below to understand how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't post the input because the code above shows no post to the controller.

If I were you I would put everything you want to send to the controller in a Html.BeginForm such as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterClient", "//ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    // This is where you will put all the input boxes and text boxes that you want to send to the  controller method

    // Submit button to send model data to method
    <button type="submit">
}
```

Obvisouly, the input details you send must match the model type provided in the method parameters. Other than this you could send the data via an ajax in javascript. The advantages of this are:

- You will not need to reload the page.
- You can reload partial views
- You could return data and populate areas of the page

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap all your inputs in the `<form></form>` tag.

```html
<div class="register-box">
    <h4 class="h4-header">Registro paso 2 de 2 </h4> 

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Register failed. Check your login details.")

    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset class="fieldset-box client-field">

            <div class="user-info-box">
                <h3> Datos de la cuenta</h3>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NombreUsuario, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Usuario" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NombreUsuario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Email" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Contraseña" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Confirmar contraseña" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="personal-info-box">
                <h3> Datos personales</h3>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Nombre" })
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Apellido, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Apellido" })
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Domicilio, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Domicilio" })
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telefono, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Telefono" })
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroDoc, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Numero de documento" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" class="but-next next round" name="upvote" value="&#8250;" />
    </form>

    <a href="#" class="but-next next round">&#8250;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your all input control needs to be inside the form. you have kept only submit button in the form, so your data will not be posted and also you have not specified the controller and action method name where the form data shall be submitted